# In Silverlight/WPF there is no way to group controls and/or have layers like in Flash?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Am I mistaken I can't anything like that ? That's a big missing feature for a Designer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Flash, so forgive me if this answer isn't really correct to a Flash user's point of view of the world.

You can create layers by placing UI elements on top of each other.  For example, if you create a `<Grid>` and place two elements in the same row/column, they will overlap each other (the last-added one being on top if you don't use Z-Index).

You can group controls together by placing them inside a Panel (like a StackPanel or Grid), or you can place them inside a UserControl which you then use somewhere else.

Does that answer your question?  If not, can you be a bit more descriptive about what the grouping/layering support in Flash does for you that you feel you may be missing in Silverlight?  There's likely an equivalent.

Comment: Well grouping with components is quite heavy. Grid is closer but not sure it fits grouping will check.